# Swift empty data set

Tags: ios, swift, dataset

I am looking to create an empty data set similar to this one. Not the looks or anything of it but just get the general concept of an empty data set. I am unsure as to how to do this and I have been wanting to implament this into my application without the use of any cocoapods. Is this easy to do? 
I am fairly new to Swift so I have not been able to figure this out. I tried the code below but there were many errors and I realized it made no sense.

```
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
if return == 0 {
        // Create the empty data set
    } else {
        return jsonfile["response"]["data"].count
    }
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The one you have shown and many others use

https://github.com/dzenbot/DZNEmptyDataSet

Also in your example it would be

```
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    let count = jsonfile["response"]["data"].count
    if count == 0 {
        return 1
    }
    return count
```

}

Then in your `cellForRow:` return a no data cell.

EDIT:

```
internal func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let count = jsonfile["response"]["data"].count
        if count == 0 {
           return noDataCell
        } else {
           return normalCell
        }
    }
```

Comment: So what would I return if it was 0 in the cellForRow? I already have a return in there that returns the results if it is greater than one

Comment: edited. replace the simple cell names with your usual cell building or a method that returns a cell dequed.